# Will I reduce the efficiency of the program if separate the functionalists of one class into several classes in c++?

Tags: c++

Just wondering whether dividing one class into several classes will reduce the efficiency of a program. In order to make my question clear, I give the following examples:

```
class OneClass
{
  public:
      Do_the_job()
      {
       Do_function1();
       Do_function2();
       Do_function3();
       }
      Do_function1();
      Do_function2();
      Do_function3();
      variables_related_to_function1;
      variables_related_to_function2;
      variables_related_to_function3;
}
```

In this class, the functionality can be divided into three sub-functions, and they are in the same class. However, for the purpose of easy maintenance, I decide to make each sub-function a class, and the whole functionality is performed by combining three independent classes in one class:

```
Class OneClass
{
public:
   Do_the_job()
   {
     class1.do_function1();
     class2.do_function2();
     class3.do_function3();
   }
   Class1 class1;
   Class2 class2;
   Class3 class3;
}
```

My question is that will the new implementation reduce the efficiency of the program. Thanks.

Comment: Even if it does take longer, the decrease in efficiency is completely negligible, so always go for the easier to understand version. Even so, I do not think that you will see any performance difference.

Comment: You really shouldn't worry about optimization before you REALLY need the extra performance. The compilers of today are great at optimization anyways. Focus on making you code easily readable and understandable, let the compiler do these kinds of optimizations.

Comment: Hard to tell, a more easily understood process might be better optimized too so you may actually gain from splitting things...

Comment: Don't forget that humans are better than compilers at high-level optimizations (such as choosing better algorithms), so it usually pays off quite a bit to have readable code because you can spot patterns and rewrite bits of code that are subject to high-level optimizations.

Comment: Your primary concern should always be maintainability and readability - CPU hours are much less expensive than programmer hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, and even if it does you're unlikely to notice.

The worst case for calling a method of another object is calling a virtual method via a pointer, which requires a vtable lookup to find the code to run, and that has to be done at runtime so it's not subject to inlining. But even that's pretty quick, and you're not going to notice it except in very specific situations.

Ordinary member functions on objects held by value is as fast as calling your own member functions.

Don't worry about things like this unless you can see that they're actually causing an issue. The impact of what kinds of function call you're making are negligible next to the potential speed problems caused by flawed algorithms, or even using postfix increment unnecessarily on some iterator classes.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you concentrate first of all on getting the logical design right, then think about these kinds of optimizations second. The kinds of optimizations that modern compilers and linkers will perform are quite impressive, and you should only worry about these kinds of performance issues after taking performance measurements / profiling.

In particular, modern linkers can do [whole program optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zza0de8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), when appropriate, which can essentially inline a method from another module, even if that module is in another statically linked library. So if the methods you're moving out are quite small, the executable code might be the essentially the same as the original.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "Probably Not". While I've never attempted to benchmark this, I do know that most developers write classes with *cohesion* in mind, rather than a specific number of functions. I  tend to only allow 10 or so functions in my class. Any more complicated than that and I need to rethink my design.

That being said, if it is any slower, the difference is probably not discernible. Unless you're doing heavy polymorphic design with many calls to the `vtable`, you shouldn't notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have multiple classes, invocation of a method still takes the same time as with  only one class. So I think there's no reason why you shouldn't split up big classes and benefit from better readability and maintainability.

What really matters is if you're starting to use virtual methods, which requires a lookup for the address of the method at runtime (if the compiler can't resolve/inline it at compile-time). In this case, the invocation takes in the order of 3 instead of 1 machine code instructions.

If you're using dynamic dispatching AND multiple inheritance, you have an overhead in the order of 4-5 machine code instructions instead of one.

That said, I should mention that you probably won't feel a noticeable difference unless you have several thousand objects of a class. But then again you could start devirtualizing your classes to reduce the overhead.